# How to share stylesheets (with a preview)?

Tags: notebooks, style, stylesheet, paclets

I have never understood how to easily generate an image preview for a given stylesheet. I also am unclear on how to easily share one. So I'm looking for an implementation or good 3rd party solution for functions to do these things:

```
StyleSheetPreview[location] (*or StyleSheetBrowse[loc] for loc in wolfram cloud that has many styles*)
```

Would give something like the built-in styles previewer:

[image]

And this would give a way to share them:

```
StyleSheetShare["newstylesheet"] (*uploads it to wolfram cloud*)
StyleSheetInstall["newstylesheet", "Uninstall" -> True|False] 
(*downloads and installs from wolfram cloud*)
```

[image]

I’ve noticed a number of `ResourceFunction`s that exist to install things (e.g. GitHubInstall). Might this be a good way to share stylesheets? Or is there another more modern way to create, preview, and deliver them stylesheets?

Comment: Paclets are designed _exactly_ for this. Use them. There's supposed to be a paclet repository coming "soon"--as in sometime in the next 5-10 years. In the meantime just distribute them as releases on GitHub.

Comment: @b3m2a1  I’ve never tried that, could you post a minimal working example of this route?

Comment: I mean like whats the directory structure, do I make a package with functions that copy or remove the style files and 9-patch images, what’s the conventions, etc. Is there a good tutorial or example of building this paclet for each new stylesheets to share?

Comment: The GitHub places I’ve looked through for sharing styles are not really “standardized” or that clear to me...

Comment: I’ll post an answer when I have the time but I’ve posted a _lot_ here about how to use paclets. I even wrote up a tutorial. Give my other answers a quick look.

Comment: But how to extend the built in theme browser would be cool too

Comment: if you mean the menu, you _also_ do that with packets. If you mean the weird little notebook where you can look at a raster of what a standard notebook looks like under different style sheets, you do that by changing that notebook in its location in the FE layout in `$UserBaseDirectory`

Comment: That would be really nice, but at least making a clean way to view the styles we bundle in paclet, easy installing and uninstalling them, is there a standard paclet documentation too?

Comment: One idea: after you figure out the paclet part of the question a concerning packaging stylesheets and installing them, you could put it on github and then use this:  https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GitHubInstall

Comment: @b3m2a1 I added a bounty so I could help repay the answer you said you'd post when you have time :)

Comment: @user5601 my bad--totally forgot about this--I'm writing up a little package to implement this and I'll post in a few mins

Answer (score 12):

#### Preview Notebooks / Extra Paclet Features

I decided it was worth it to add some extra features to this thing as it's a good example of what paclets can do for you.

First off, I added a little `CreateStylesheetPreview` function that'll take stylesheets and rasterize them to make a preview. e.g.:

```
CreateStylesheetPreview[
  {"Default.nb", "ReverseColor.nb" -> "Custom/CodeNotebook.nb"}
  ] // CreateDocument
```

[image]

(Read the [source code](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/StylesheetShare.wl) to see how it's implemented. It's not particularly complex stuff.)

Then I made it so that you can `"Include"` arbitrary content in your paclet, so we'll add this as a palette. I'll do that as a directory, just to show how it works. Other content can be included directly as files, but I wanted to support both. First we'll create a directory containing the palettes of interest:

```
Quiet@
  CreateDirectory["~/Desktop/Palettes/Custom/", 
   CreateIntermediateDirectories -> True];
Export[
  "~/Desktop/Palettes/Custom/CodeNotebookPreview.nb",
  CreateStylesheetPreview[
   {"Default.nb", "ReverseColor.nb" -> "Custom/CodeNotebook.nb"}
   ]
  ];
```

then we can bundle and share it like so:

```
StylesheetShare[
 sheets[[1]],
 "Includes" -> {
   "~/Desktop/Palettes/Custom" -> "FrontEnd/Palettes/Custom",
   "~/Desktop/StylesheetShare.wl"
   },
 "PackageContext" -> {"StylesheetShare`"}
 ]

CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/b3m2a1.testing/Paclets/CodeNotebook-1.0.0.paclet"]
```

You'll notice I also included the package that implements this stuff in there, just for the heck of it.

When you install it, since I didn't bump the `"Version"` in the `Options`, if you have an old version installed you'll need to install it like so:

```
StylesheetInstall["CodeNotebook", "IgnoreVersion" -> True]

Paclet[CodeNotebook, 1.0.0, <>]
```

Once it's installed you'll see two changes from before, first, in the palettes menu we have this:

[image]

which just opens up that preview notebook from before.

Second, we can find that installed package:

```
FindFile["StylesheetShare`"] // StringTrim[#, $UserBasePacletsDirectory] &

"/Repository/CodeNotebook-1.0.0/Include/StylesheetShare.wl"
```

And so at that point you could just do `` <<StylesheetShare` `` to load the package

If you want to distribute multiple packages you can do that by adding their names to the `"PackageContext"` list.

#### Original

Wrote up a package to do the sharing.

First load the package from GitHub:

```
Get["https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/raw/master/StylesheetShare.wl"]
```

This exposes two functions, `StylesheetShare` and `StylesheetInstall`

Next get some sheets to share. Here are a few that are already in a package of mine:

```
stylesheetsDir = 
  "~/Documents/Wolfram Mathematica/Applications/BTools/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/BTools";

sheets =
 FileNames[
  "*.nb", 
  stylesheetsDir
  ]

(* Out:

{
 ~/Documents/Wolfram Mathematica/Applications/BTools/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/BTools/CodeNotebook.nb,
 ~/Documents/Wolfram Mathematica/Applications/BTools/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/BTools/CodePackage.nb,
 ~/Documents/Wolfram Mathematica/Applications/BTools/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/BTools/CodePackagePlain.nb,
 ~/Documents/Wolfram Mathematica/Applications/BTools/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/BTools/DocGen.nb,
 ~/Documents/Wolfram Mathematica/Applications/BTools/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/BTools/MarkdownNotebook.nb,
 ~/Documents/Wolfram Mathematica/Applications/BTools/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/BTools/SyntaxHighlighting.nb
 }

*)
```

Then we can share a single sheet:

```
StylesheetShare[
 sheets[[1]]
 ]

CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/b3m2a1.testing/Paclets/CodeNotebook-1.0.0.paclet"]
```

And then install that:

```
StylesheetInstall[
 "CodeNotebook", 
 "WolframID" -> "b3m2a1.testing"
 ]

Paclet[CodeNotebook,1.0.0,<>]
```

[image]

Or you can share the entire directory:

```
StylesheetShare[
 stylesheetsDir,
 "Name" -> "MySheets"
 ]

CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/b3m2a1.testing/Paclets/MySheets-1.0.0.paclet"]
```

There are a bunch of little settings you can use in `StylesheetShare` if you want:

```
Options[StylesheetShare]

{"Version" -> "1.0.0", "Name" -> Automatic, "Creator" -> Automatic, 
 "Description" -> "A stylesheets paclet", 
 "BuildDirectory" :> CreateDirectory[], "MenuName" -> "Custom", 
 "PacletsRoot" -> "", Permissions -> "Public", AppearanceElements -> All, 
 AutoCopy -> False, CloudObjectNameFormat -> Automatic, 
 CloudObjectURLType -> Automatic, IconRules -> Automatic, 
 MetaInformation -> {}, SharingList -> {}, SourceLink -> Automatic}
```

But that should be enough to get you started

Comment: Can you give some suggestions as to how the preview gallery would work?

Comment: @user5601 basically you’d set up a `Notebook` with all the content you’d like to see as changes (basically standard cell styles), then `Rasterize` it with a set of different style sheets set as the `StyleDefinitions`. You can get all of the stylesheet available in the styles menu using something like ``FEPrivate`GetMenuPopupList``

Comment: What about if the stylesheet as lots of custom non-standard cell style names

Comment: @user5601 you’ll make a custom template `Notebook` for the preview, I figure. No way good way to get _only_ the relevant cell styles programmatically (there are usually lots of like `TemplateBox` styles in there too).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, to support any sort of "share with preview" I'll need to package two things 1. styledefinitions notebook 2. a template notebook using (1).  Ok but then what do I do with both of those files, your  StylesheetShare works for just (1) right?

Comment: @user5601 I'll write up an extension to make it easy to include other directories. You can include your previews as a palette or something or add a package that will generate it when called.